# Move Columns To Lines R

Tags: r

I have this kind of data frame at the moment :

```
 gauche droite
1        0      1
2        0      0
3        1      0
4        0      0
5        0      0
6        0      0
7        0      0
8        0      0
9        0      0
10       0      0
11       0      0
```

and would like to display the rows in a list, having:

```
[row1,column1], [row1,column2],[row2,column1],[row2,column2],[row3,column1][row3,column2] etc....
```

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "as a list". List is a special structure in R and it's not clear if that's what you're after. Also, consider sharing your data in an easy to paste form.

Comment: Does `c(t(your_data))` give you what you want?

Comment: It would just be a lot more clear if you showed a concrete example of your desired output

Comment: @akrun I have no idea if it is. I mean... it probably is but the desired output isn't clear to me so I'm not sure what question would be the appropriate dupe candidate.

Comment: I do not get the pattern...(1,1) (1,2) (2,1) (2,2) (3,1) (3,2) then what? Any recursive formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `purrr::transpose` to transpose a list (a data frame is a list).

Comment: It worked, thank you !

Comment: @EEFB If you are happy with the answer, please validate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
N=10
gauche<-rep(1:N)
droite<-ifelse(runif(N)>0.5,1,0)
resultat<-expand.grid(gauche,droite)
```

resulting in:

```
lapply(c(1,4,6),function(x) paste0(resultat[x,]))

[[1]]
[1] "1" "0"

[[2]]
[1] "4" "0"

[[3]]
[1] "6" "0"
```

## PS:

Of course the `c(1,4,6)` is arbitrary. OP needs to update the initial request in order to better formulate the answer.